# Using find to locate files modified in Aug

Tags: linux, find, mtime

I need to find files modified in August.  Here's my portion of the command that narrows down the modification time.  This works, but it seems to be missing some files.  I'm guessing this is missing files modified in a given hour or hour(s) because the numbers change depending on what part of the day that I run this script.  I'm looking at the `-mmin` parameter but am struggling with how to exactly implement it.  I'm looking for all files modified between `Aug 1 - 31`.

```
    $dayOfMonth = date("j");
    $daysLastMonth = date("t", strtotime('-1 month'));
    $secondsSinceMidnight = time() - strtotime('00:00');
    $secondsUntilMidnight = (60*60*24) - $secondsSinceMidnight;
    $commandAppend = " -name '*.pdf' -mtime -".($dayOfMonth+$daysLastMonth)." -mtime +".($dayOfMonth)." | wc -l";
```

Answer (score 1):

You could to something with the `-newer` switch

```
touch -d "01 AUG 2012" start
touch -d "31 AUG 2012 23:59:59" end
find /path -newer start -not -newer end
```

Which will find files that are newer than the file `start` and not newer that the file `end`

> -newer file
>
> ```
>           File was modified more recently than file.  If file  is  a  sym-
>           bolic  link and the -H option or the -L option is in effect, the
>           modification time of the file it points to is always used.
> ```

```
sudo find /home -newer start | wc -l
41597
sudo find /home -newer start -not -newer end | wc -l
41568
sudo find /home -newer end | wc -l
29
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create two files using `touch -t` representing the start and end of your duration. Then, you can use `find` with `-newer` option. The detailed answered is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5893913/471547).

Comment: That gives me the error `find: missing argument to `-exec'` when I run `find "/path-to-pdfs/" -name '*.pdf' -newer /script_files/tmpStartModificationTime ! -newer /script_files/tmpEndModificationTime -exec ls -s {}\;`